# Protractor Locators, is there a way to find elements using generic search string?

Tags: selenium, protractor

Given:

```
<span>{{person.name}}</span>
<span ng-bind="person.email"></span>
```

Question:

Is there anyway I can use a Protractor locator like this:

```
var eles = element.all(by.binding('person.*'));
```

Or better yet...

```
var eles = element.all(by.binding('*'));
```

I'm wanting to find all elements that are "bound" without knowing the binding string before hand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular CSS selector would do the job. E.g. getting all elements that have a `person` in binding:

```
$$("[ng-bind*=person]");  // *= means "contains".
```

Or, all elements having a binding (having the `ng-bind` attribute):

```
$$("[ng-bind]");
```

Or, `$$(".ng-binding")` - FYI, this is [how Protractor internally locates the elements with a binding](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L122).

where `$$` is a shortcut for `element.all(by.css())`.

<sub>Note that this would not work if `data-ng-bind` is used, for example. You may tweak the expression to handle that.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for quick reply... What does the asterisk mean?  Can I put an asterisk on right side of equals sign to find all ng-binds?

Comment: @JohnPeters updated the answer with some more information. Hope that helps.

Comment: @alecxe thanks, I did not know about the asterisk usage!